# How to use meteors own non-core packages when running from a git checkout

Tags: meteor

When running meteor from a git checkout, there are 2 packages available at path

```
<meteor-path>/packages/non-core
    npm-bcrypt/
    npm-node-aes-gcm/
```

How to use/enable these packages (best practise) on own project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much easier than symlink is just setting the `PACKAGE_DIRS` env var. Have a look at https://forums.meteor.com/t/missing-non-core-packages-when-running-meteor-from-checkout/1140 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the published versions of your packages already, because they're on Atmosphere:

```
meteor add npm-bcrypt
```

If you want to use specifically their git checkout versions, you need to create a `packages` subdirectory in your app's directory, and symlink there the paths to the packages.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your answer. That was what I was looking for: "symlink". I just thought it by myself but wanted to have someone confirm this. Thanks.